# Add color to match text highlighting in twitter typeahead

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js, typeahead

As far as I can tell there's no configuration for the styling of text matched in the suggestion box. Is there something I'm missing? Would just like to *color* the text matching the search query, rather than *bold* it.

Answer (score 5):

By default twitter typeahead.js wrap the matches into `<strong>` tags. So if you just want to change the color of the matching text, you could simply just style the `<strong>` tag :

```css
strong {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: red;
}
```

you probably only want to style `<strong>` within the dropdown :

```css
.tt-suggestion strong {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: red;
}
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/vrs95w3g/**

There is also some highlight where you are supposed to be able to change the tagName and className, but honestly never got it to work. Still prefers the good old bootstrap typeahead :)

Here is btw a good example how to style typeahead.js in general (border, input, dropdown etc) -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/20205623/1407478

Comment: Simple and yet effective. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. don't know it I got the question right. for me,  (in  * typeahead.js 0.11.1)  it lookd like it's another class name : highlight: "tt-highlight"   in typeahead.bunle.js, you can get all the classes at the definition of variable defaultClassNames  if this helps..

Comment: @user3617487, Thank you so much for pointing this out! You were kind of right, the selector was wrong, it should be `tt-suggestion` not `tt-suggestions`. Have updated the fiddle, also added the correct 0.11.1 CSS which was missing. Now the typeahead look as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Gonna go one up, and give the code for fuzzy highlighting

```
function fuzzyMe(term, query) {
  var score = 0;
  var termLength = term.length;
  var queryLength = query.length;
  var highlighting = '';
  var ti = 0;
  // -1 would not work as this would break the calculations of bonus
  // points for subsequent character matches. Something like
  // Number.MIN_VALUE would be more appropriate, but unfortunately
  // Number.MIN_VALUE + 1 equals 1...
  var previousMatchingCharacter = -2;
  for (var qi = 0; qi < queryLength && ti < termLength; qi++) {
    var qc = query.charAt(qi);
    var lowerQc = qc.toLowerCase();

    for (; ti < termLength; ti++) {
      var tc = term.charAt(ti);

      if (lowerQc === tc.toLowerCase()) {
        score++;

        if ((previousMatchingCharacter + 1) === ti) {
          score += 2;
        }

        highlighting += "<em>" + tc + "</em>";
        previousMatchingCharacter = ti;
        ti++;
        break;
      } else {
        highlighting += tc;
      }
    }
  }

  highlighting += term.substring(ti, term.length);

  return {
    score: score,
    term: term,
    query: query,
    highlightedTerm: highlighting
  };
}
```

The above takes care of the fuzziness. Then you can just iterate over all your select 2 elements

On typeahead:change

```
$('#search-bar').typeahead({....}).on('change', function(e) {                     
    var query = $('#search-bar').typeahead('val'); 
     $(".tt-suggestion.tt-selectable .name").each(function() {
        var term = $(this).text();
        $(this).html(fuzzyMe(term, query).highlightedTerm);
      });
});
```

Credit for fuzzy code -: https://github.com/bripkens/fuzzy.js