# twitter tyepahead CSS rendering issue

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5, typeahead.js

I am using twitter bootstrap with Bloodhound. I am getting results and autocomplete working fine, but I am missing CSS. Could you please help me fixing the issue. 
Here is the **screen print for my issue:** 
http://postimg.org/image/txpucyhyr/
I tried my level best, but I am new to MVC and Jquery technologies. 
I am using 
asp.net MVC 5.2.2
Bootstrap v3.3.4
typeahead.js 0.10.5

My BundleConfig & JS Scripts: http://postimg.org/image/bjfb8z5o3/

Here is my HTMLcode:

```
        <div id="divCause" class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CauseNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" id="CauseNumber" name="CauseNumber" class="typeahead" data-provide="typeahead" placeholder="Cause Number" autocomplete="off" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

customJQuery.cs

```
    var csNumbers = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('Value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    //,prefetch: '/path/to/prefetch',
    remote: './GetData?term=%QUERY' // you can use this for ajax call
});

csNumbers.initialize();

$('#CauseNumber.typeahead').typeahead(null,
{
    name: 'label',
    displayKey: 'label',
    source: csNumbers.ttAdapter()
    //remote: 'Search/GetData?term=%QUERY'
});
```

Controller

```
        public JsonResult GetData(string term)
    {
        var model = objUtil.getCauseNumbers(term).Select(r => new { label = r.CauseNumber });
        return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Dhiraj. Looks like my problem resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I got answer for my issue from the following post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26934329/4755915
 Dhiraj helped me in finding the solution.